# Why can't I run my laravel app with PHP artisan serve?

Tags: php, laravel, port, laravel-artisan, serve

I'm working on a laravel app. I made the simple installation of a new laravel app, and in the previous days it was running great.

But now I'm not able to access my project in browser after running php artisan serve. The browser just says page not found and the buffering of that page is like infinite.

I tried to run the server in a different port with:

```
php artisan serve --port=9000
```

and then accessed it in http://127.0.0.1:9000/

It run well once, but then it stopped again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try out the following:

- `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` To run withe inbuilt PHP server
- Make a fresh installation of a laravel project and copy your files into it.

Comment: the code I tried is really just the commands in cmder command line:
> php artisan serve 
> php artisan serve --port=9000
and there were no error message, just the behaviour I described above.

And thank you that command worked.
I'm just concerned about this: 
that command runs the same thing as **php artisan serve** ? because I think artisan runs some more proccesses than just php, or my wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Running `php artisan serve` simply runs `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`. But the major advantage of this is that it can attach Laravel's debugger during it's execution. So, to be on the safer side, just use `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me but I used composer:

```
php artisan serve --port=9000
```

Then it hanged. I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and I got it working without any errors

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, I got solved by these;**

1) Change the default url to like this - `localhost/<your-project-name>/public/` instead of default one `127.0.0.1:8000`

or

2) use this `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` or `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`